# сделать скролинг блока по вертикали

Tags: css, прокрутка

На странице есть блок с видео и текстовым контентом справа от него. Как сделать так, чтобы у текстового контента был только вертикальный скролл и не было горизонтального? [Ссылка](http://new.pozdravideo.ru/video/item/eldzhej-pozdravlyaet-po-imeni-s-dnem-rozhdeniya-copy-2-copy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для дочерних элементов класса `pos-content` добавьте свойство `max-width: 275px;`, чтобы текст умещался в контейнер.
А горизонтальный скролл у вас уже скрыт.